# Python: When do I execute the class->function-> Parenthesis. & Matplotlib figure wont show

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am stuck. I have tried to code a figure into Tk from Matplotlib. I have done it before, but for some reason this is just not working.

I also don't understand when to use "()" to call a function and when not too:

```
#Example
def _Example(self)
    print "Blah blah"

# Do I call?
self._Example  # or
self._Example()
```

Sometimes one works and one doesn't?? AKA in the case of "events" in my code _UpdateCanvas??

That would be helpful, because now I can't seem to find out why my figure isn't loading?

```
# ----------------------- Import <<
from Tkinter import *
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
# ----------------------- Class <<
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self._job = None
        self.canvas = None
        self.Flag_Zoom = False
        self.pack()
        self._Data()        
        self._GUI_Design()

        # Create Canvas + Load Canvas
        self._Figure(self.Arm,self.Tri)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f,self.LF_Graph)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.show()

    def _GUI_Design(self):
        # FRAME
        self.LF_Control = LabelFrame(self, text='Angle Controls', width=400, height=100 )
        self.LF_Graph = LabelFrame(self, text='Figure', width=400, height=400)
        self.LF_Control.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5,pady=1)
        self.LF_Graph.grid(row=1, column=0,padx=5,pady=3)

        # LABELS
        self.LB_Info = Label(self.LF_Control,text="MOTION CONTACT EXAMPLE\nwith spoiler controls\n2013-07-23", justify=LEFT)
        self.LB_SP = Label(self.LF_Control, text="Spoiler:")
        self.LB_FP = Label(self.LF_Control, text="Triangle:")

        # SLIDERS
        self.SpScale = Scale(self.LF_Control, from_=0, to=45, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=350, resolution=1, command=self._UpdateCanvas, tickinterval=5)
        self.TrScale = Scale(self.LF_Control, from_=0, to=180, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=350, resolution=5, command=self._UpdateCanvas, tickinterval=30)

        # BUTTONS
        self.Bup = Button(self.LF_Control, text="  ^  \n  |  ", command=self._Bup)
        self.Bdn = Button(self.LF_Control, text="  |  \n  V  ", command=self._Bdn)
        self.Blf = Button(self.LF_Control, text=" <- "  , command=self._Blf)
        self.Brt = Button(self.LF_Control, text=" -> "  , command=self._Brt)

        # GRIDS
        self.LB_Info.grid(row=0, column=0,padx=1,pady=1,columnspan=2)
        self.LB_SP.grid(row=1, column=0,padx=1,pady=1)
        self.LB_FP.grid(row=2, column=0,padx=1,pady=1)
        self.SpScale.grid(row=1, column=1,padx=1,pady=1)
        self.TrScale.grid(row=2, column=1,padx=1,pady=1)
        self.Bup.grid(row=0, column=4 ,padx=1,pady=1)
        self.Bdn.grid(row=2, column=4 ,padx=1,pady=1)
        self.Blf.grid(row=1, column=3 ,padx=1,pady=1)
        self.Brt.grid(row=1, column=5 ,padx=1,pady=1)
        print "Graphics Loaded"

    def _Figure(self,Arm,Tri):
        self.f = plt.figure(1)      

        plt.axis([-500,500,-500,500])
        plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
        plt.plot(Arm[0],Arm[1],"r")
        plt.plot(Tri[0],Tri[1],"g")
        print "figure set",Arm,Tri

    def _UpdateCanvas(self,event):
        print "def:_UpdateCanvas"
        self._job = self.after(100, self._Execute)  #miliseconds
        if self._job:
            self.after_cancel(self._job)

    def _Data(self):
        self.Arm  = [[0,100],[0,100]]
        self.Tri = [[50,150,100,50],[-50,-40,-120,-50]]

    def _Execute(self):
        print "def:_Execute"        
        self.SpAngle =  self.SpScale.get()
        self.TrAngle =  self.TrScale.get()

        self._Figure(self.Arm,self.Tri)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.show()

    # Button Commands
    def _Bup(self):
        self.Tri[1] = [i+5 for i in self.Tri[1]]
        print "Button: UP"
        self._Execute()
    def _Bdn(self):
        self.Tri[1] = [i-5 for i in self.Tri[1]]
        print "Button: DOWN"        
        self._Execute()
    def _Blf(self):
        self.Tri[0] = [i-5 for i in self.Tri[0]]
        print "Button: LEFT"                
        self._Execute()
    def _Brt(self):
        self.Tri[0] = [i+5 for i in self.Tri[0]]
        print "Button: RIGHT"                
        self._Execute()      


# Execute App
root = Tk()
root.title("Contact")
Exe = App(master=root)
root.mainloop()
```

Please me understand why no figures are loading?

Comment: You always call functions in Python using `()`, so `self.Example()` calls the function.  Without the parentheses you are referring to the function as an object, which you often do when you want to pass a function as an argument to another function, you are doing this when you set up your buttons - `self.Brt = Button(self.LF_Control, text=" -> "  , command=self._Brt)`  - here self._Brt is a reference to a function, and it is passed into `Button`, it is not executed at this point.

Comment: Are any error reported when you run this, or do you just not see anything happen when you press a button?  Are the 'BUTTON UP' etc messages printed out?

Comment: Thanks Steve that does help. Just so its clear an **Object** can have an event? Is that the reason `_UpdateCanvas(self,event)` executes? 

I do actually get the Button_Up print, but still no Figure to load. Though I will check my objects/functions.
Output

`Graphics Loaded
def:_UpdateCanvas
def:_UpdateCanvas
def:_Execute
def:_Execute
Button: UP
def:_Execute
Button: UP
def:_Execute
Button: UP
def:_Execute
Button: UP
def:_Execute
Button: UP
def:_Execute`

Comment: Is there any reason why I can't do this? 
`self.Brt = Button(self.LF_Control, text=" -> "  , command=self._UpdateCanvas(4))`
       
....for some reason Tk.widgets requires `commands=` to be objects instead of functions?

Comment: In this `self.Brt = Button(self.LF_Control, text=" -> " , command=self._UpdateCanvas(4))` the `(4)` after `_UpdateCanvas` means that `_UpdateCanvas` is called, and `command` is set to be whatever it returns.  By setting `command=self._UpdateCanvas` you are passing in the `_UpdateCanvas` function itself as the `command` argument.  Somewhere inside the code for `Button` there will be some code that calls the function you have passed in when the button is clicked, `_UpdateCanvas` is in this case being used as a 'callback function'.  This is a very common thing in UI toolkits.

Comment: The output you gave above - the `def:_Execute` and `Button: UP` are logged when you actually click the button or when the app starts up?  Is `print "figure set",Arm,Tri` working, it looks like that should be logged right after `def:_Execute`.

Comment: Also, if you are embedding `matplotlib` in a gui, do not import `plt`

Comment: and can you reduce this down to the _minimum_ amount of code needed to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: @tcaswell I would love to know how to eliminated the loading of **`plt`**. As it stands I still can't get the figure to load into the label frame.

Please feel free to send any code that I could learn from.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always use parenthesis to call a function. You never use parenthesis if you are using the function as a parameter to a `command` attribute, or when using it in a bind statement.

The trick is knowing when you want to *call* a function, and when you want to use a *reference* to the function. With respect to Tkinter, the value of a `command` attribute, and the second argument to a `bind` statement must always be a reference to a function that will be called later.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan, I think the thing that confused me was that `Button(commend=####)` referenced as an object-> the function, while the `self.after(100, #####)` calls a function. Now that's sorted out I just need to figure out why the figure is not getting loaded into the LabelFrame

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I found the reason why the figure wasn't loading. 

the `self.canvas` requires a get command `self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)` that was missing.